# How to solve Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ListViewAdapter.IsEnabled Exception?

Tags: xamarin, exception, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a list with some user's selected items. My CustumCellViewTemplate has an "unselect" control, which removes the cell from the list.
When the list is entirely filled with items, the "unselect" control works, but when I want to remove the last item or if the last item appears in the ListView, then I got this Exception:

```
"System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ListViewAdapter.IsEnabled (System.Int32 position) [0x0002a] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\Renderers\ListViewAdapter.cs:413 
at Android.Widget.BaseAdapter.n_IsEnabled_I (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.Int32 position) [0x00008] in <263adecfa58f4c449f1ff56156d886fd>:0 
at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object.389216aa-a260-49e0-aaaa-e4e2031ad22f(intptr,intptr,int)"
```

This is my config:

```
Mono 8.1
Xamarin.Forms 3.3.0.893527-pre3
Xamarin.Android.Support.Design 27.0.2.1
Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat 27.0.2.1
Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 27.0.2.1
Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView 27.0.2.1
Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter 27.0.2.1
Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Location 60.1142.1
Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps 60.1142.1
Xamarin.Essentials 0.10.0-preview
```

Do you have any idea how to solve this issue, please ?

Regards

Comment: how are you removing items from the list?

Comment: Hi Jason,
Originaly I was doing with a method:
`var newList = WishList;
newList.RemoveAll(item => item.Key == itemToBeRemovedKey);
WishList = newList.OrderBy(item => item.Distance).ToList();`

After I change for a command doing this:
`WishList.Remove(ItemToBeRemoved);`

I get an Exception with both ways.

Comment: I think the problem is partially coming from my CustumCellViewTemplate which was toggling the controlImage from "SelectedItemImage" to "UnselectedItem". I removed this feature, since I am removing the item from the ListView, it does not matter to toggle the controlImage.
It solved the problem when removing with the the CustumCellViewTemplate's control.
But I still get an issue when being in the DetailView, unselecting the item and coming back to the List. Then I get this :
`requestLayout() improperly called by md515582337f2c37.PageRenderer{310e} during layout: running second layout pass`

Answer (score 3):

You might have solved your issue by now but just leaving this here for other people that run into this.

Thanks to Jason's question it lead me to clean up my manipulation of the bindable itemsource for the list view logic. I was doing a lot of .Clear() and Add that I didn't need to do. I reduced the number of these and it fixed the issue for me. So I would look at how you are messing with the ItemSource for the list view.

Comment: This answer is great - I had background thread code that was doing a .Clear() on the ObservableCollection and then .Add()'ing items and I was able to get past the exception by building the new collection in a temp var and then setting it all at once, avoiding the use of .Clear().

Comment: Yeah this keeps happening on just Droid and it seems like the newer version of Forms don't fix this either.

Answer (score 0):

I was too facing this with **`ListView`** in `TabbedPage` so while changing tabs I was resetting `ItemSource` of `Listview`, solved my issue

```
protected void OnCurrentPageChanged()
{
    if (Children != null && CurrentPage != null)
    {
        list1.ItemsSource = null;
        list2.ItemsSource = null;
        list3.ItemsSource = null;

        SelectedTabIndex = Children.IndexOf(this.CurrentPage);

        if (SelectedTabIndex == 0)
            list1.ItemsSource = TimeTableListData;
        if  (SelectedTabIndex == 1)
            list2.ItemsSource = TimeTableListData;
        if (SelectedTabIndex == 2)
            list3.ItemsSource = TimeTableListData;
    }
}
```